# MSYS sh.exe breaks when trying to make

Tags: cmd, g++, mingw, mingw32, msys

I ran MSYS's sh.exe and tried to make, but after g++ execution simply got cmd.exe window. Here the screenshot:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11635312/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It probably successfully finished. If a command is successful, it writes nothing in the shell. Did you check whether it generated the program you were trying to compile?

Comment: Nothing is generated. Also, if I use mingw32-make then compilation is successful and I stll stay in sh.exe after

Comment: Proccess sh.exe still exists when I get cmd.exe invitation line. It terminates when cmd.exe closes

Comment: Yes. Why is that a problem? And more importantly:  Did you check whether it generated the program you were trying to compile?